# Two fragments in one page of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm searching solution of my problem. I have to make app using 3 fragments - just like on the picture. [Picture of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDkU4.jpg) 
I'm using ViewPager to have swipeable tabs which are required. But there is a problem - i can't set two fragments into one page of ViewPager.

```
public class ProgrammingLanguageInfo extends FragmentActivity{

private String languageName;
private int languageImageID;
private String languageDescription;
private String SHARED_PREFERENCES;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);
    languageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("LANGUAGE_NAME");
    languageImageID = getIntent().getIntExtra("LANGUAGE_IMAGE", 0);
    languageDescription = getIntent().getStringExtra("LANGUAGE_DESCRIPTION");
    SHARED_PREFERENCES = getIntent().getStringExtra("LANGUAGE_SHARED_PREFERENCES");

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        if(pos==0){
            return FirstFragment.newInstance(languageName, languageImageID, languageDescription, SHARED_PREFERENCES);
        }
        else{
            return SecondFragment.newInstance("aaa");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

The problem comes in function ***getItem(int pos)***. On page number 0 everything is ok - there is one fragment to display. But how to display two fragments on next page of ViewPager? I can't return two Fragments from this function.

Comment: Did you try orientation in your XML viewpager code?
`android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial. Hoe this will help!

https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/android-multiple-fragments-stack-in-each-viewpager-tab/

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply!
Unfortunately, in this tutorial there is only one fragment at once on ViewPager's page. In my case, problem is to have two fragments at the same time on one page.

But thanks anyway!

Comment: Hey, sorry for the wrong answer. Nevertheless, I guess in this case you have to create three fragments for your "Second Pager Item". One will work as a parent/container in which other two fragments will be as child fragments/ frame layouts. From your Pager Main method you will call the instance of "Parent Fragment", this parent will be having two fragments within it.

Answer (score 0):

as a sollution you need to make a fragment that contains the 2 fragments as a child fragment  instead of getSupportedFragment call

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

and the other parts of creating and showing a fragment 
make a xml that should use two containers for the fragments to use

and finaly return the above fragment as 2secon frag

Comment: Okay, I will try to do this and give feedback how is it going :)